# How to get negotiated cipher using OpenSSL library

Tags: openssl

Using the OpenSSL library API, after calling SSL_connect() in a TLS client, how do I find out which cipher (and protocol) was actually negotiated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [SSL_get_current_cipher](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/ssl/SSL_get_current_cipher.html) to find out which cipher was negotiated as part of the handshake.

> SSL_get_current_cipher() returns a pointer to an SSL_CIPHER object
>   containing the description of the actually used cipher of a connection
>   established with the ssl object.

You can get the protocol version from the `version` field in the `SSL` object.

```
SSL *s;
/* handshake */
int version = s->version;
```

Comment: This worked - thank you! Also - to get a string value of the cipher, do SSL_CIPHER_get_name(cipher).  And to get a string value of the protocol, use SSL_get_version(ssl).